# Unity on Linux gives CS0518 error. System.$Everything is not defined

Tags: c#, linux, unity-game-engine, mono

This is an odd error. I've tried making pretty much the same program (a basic script that prints when a button is pressed) in Unity and in a console app. Only in the Unity version does it give out all these errors. I've seen a few things about setting the VersionFramework but none of these have worked. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Please show your source code, and also, does the error point its finger at a particular line/column in your source code?

Comment: @KirkWoll, nothing is getting pointed to. It doesn't matter what code I use. If it's got a variable in it then it's broken. I took some guaranteed working code from an older project and tried to build it and it broke.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by reinstalling the Mono kit.

```
sudo apt-get remove mono-complete
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This is how I fixed it at least. Just make sure you have all C# programs and Monodevelop and Unity and all that stuff closed so it doesn't glitch out and scramble any data.

Hopefully this can help someone else having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create new project in monodevelop. Then open in folder of project .csproj file. Find FrameworkVersion. Example:
    < TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5< /TargetFrameworkVersion>
Set this version in self project in csproj.